# The "click event" does not work in Python Plotly

Tags: python, events, graph, click, plotly

I have tried using the code from this page:

https://plot.ly/python/click-events/

It does not work in Visual Studio Code and in a Jupyter Notebook.

What could be the reason for this and how could I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and just resolved this, the problem for me was that the widgets extension had not been enabled correctly (as I could check from executing jupyter nbextension list, the output was empty). If it’s empty can you try in your conda env:

```
jupyter nbextension enable --py widgetsnbextension
```

see the documentation here: https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/4.x/examples/Notebook/rstversions/Distributing%20Jupyter%20Extensions%20as%20Python%20Packages.html#enable-nbextension-assets

Comment: facing the same issue. My extension is activated but the example still does not work.